# Centering .col-md-x on bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, center

How could I center the .col-md-8 (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) on bootstrap valid html?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the class col-md-offset-2.  Or you can create a div inside of your column div and use a class of content-center.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Bootstrap class [`.mx-auto`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
        <p>Content with 8 columns in md</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was a little bit of hacky, but it works:

Just use `col-md-2` `div`s before and after your main `col-md-8` `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the class .row-centered to the row and .col-centered to the columns.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-centered">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-centered"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row-centered {text-align:center;}
.col-centered { display:inline-block; float:none; margin-right:-4px;}
```